# Vinca (Madagascar Periwinkle) not growing

Tags: houseplants

[image][image]I planted hybrid vinca plant 21 days ago but not yet growing. I potted in potting in 60% red soil, 20% coco peat, 20% compost.  What is the reason please help

Answer (score 0):

Vincas are native to tropical rainforests, so ideally they have growth spurts in rainy weather. Are you providing them with abundant sunlight? . I'd suggest you to conduct a little experiment. Give them a plentiful watering and then cover the potted plant in plastic bag for upto two weeks . This'll mimic humid environment and the lateral buds will go into growth spurts. Apparently you've sprayed them with Mancozeb + Carbendazim mix. So there'll be no threat of fungal growth in humid conditions, but I'll suggest you to check the plants in experiment under humud regularly to eliminate any signs of fungus.

Fertilize them with a succulent mix often.

Comment: Okay I will try